# Font changing size on different pages

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, navigation

I have a navigation bar I am importing via an include and php. The code is exactly the same but the font is rendering different on each page.

This is how I'd like the top navigation bar font to look.

http://www.ravepreservationproject.com/

but for some reason when I import the same include onto another page the font doubles its thickness.

http://www.ravepreservationproject.com/gallery/index.php#*

Does anyone know what the issue may be and how to resolve it?

NOTE: I have checked the css to see if something is over writing the font size but there is nothing in the code doing so.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: what browser do you see the problem in? I see text alignment prob in FF on MAC removing height on the #header fixed that.

Comment: thank you chris. chrome, ff, and ie on win 8

Comment: i commented out #header height. i am still having an issue with the font weight. the weird thing is that i only see the font weight different on my desktop not my laptop.

Comment: Could it be the height of the window causing the font rendering issue? on a laptop both pages probably need scrolling while on desktop the flag page prob doesn't. A way to fix that issue is to force pages to have a scroll bar on the right with css or javascript. See if you can fix the prob just resizing your desktop browser window.

Comment: Just took a look in the head tag and I dont see the Roboto font from google loaded on both pages... Could one be from google and the other from peoples system?

Comment: hmmm, i call roboto in the css so it "should" be loading on both pages (same css) but i will have a look and ensure it is doing so.

Comment: you are in fact calling it in the css but Roboto seems to available on your system without Googles help. Googles version of the font is slightly different than your systems version.

Comment: ah i see what you are saying. that makes sense. how do i ensure the same font is loaded all the time?

Answer (score 0):

The navbar is showing the same styling on both pages for me, if I understand what you're asking correctly.  What browser are you using?  It could be a cross-browser issue.

Comment: the font changes weight in chrome on my desktop (win 8 64b). looks fine in ie and ff. looks fine on all browsers on my laptop. maybe it is a cache issue.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with your element.style tag, see if that is working properly for both pages.

Comment: i'll have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its Google fonts serving Roboto on one page and not the other. Check your head tags and remove the call to Google fonts but keep Roboto in your CSS to see what i mean.

You can either make sure you load google fonts on all pages or dont load google fonts. Just be consistent.

Why google fonts are being called on one page and not the other is another question.